# Can you measure whether a non excited electron in an atom is radiating or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics

Recently, I heard someone saying that even when an electron exists in an orbital around an atom it is still emitting electromagnetic (EM) radiation. Of course, from a classical perspective, I was told that when an electron orbits the nucleus of an atom it would eventually collide with the nucleus because it would be radiating EM waves. Now I also know that it is wrong to say that an electron is *orbiting* the nucleus, but are electrons 'still' emitting EM radiation even if it is not in an excited state? If so, what kind of radiation is this?

There are some [related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70200/why-electrons-cant-radiate-in-their-atoms-orbits) questions and answers about this subject. So it appears that a non-excited electron would not be radiating EM radiation. Most of the answers are based on a theory (QED). However, isn't it possible to just measure whether a non-exited atom is radiating?

Comment: yes it is rediating

Comment: No. See [Why electrons can't radiate in their atoms' orbits?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70200/why-electrons-cant-radiate-in-their-atoms-orbits)