# Why don't atoms constantly emit light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, atoms

We know that accelerating charged particles emit electromagnetic radiation. We also know that electrons around nucleus have an angular momentum which means that electrons are revolving around the nucleus, therefore, they are subjected to acceleration due to their orbital motion. However, atoms do not constantly emit light. Isn’t this a contradiction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why electrons can't radiate in their atoms' orbits?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70200/)

Comment: This is indeed a contradiction, which motivated the development of quantum mechanics. A better atom model is the [Bohr model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model), where electron orbits must have specific energies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't electrons crash into the nuclei they "orbit"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/)

Comment: You need to include  the quantum mechanics tag, for more than one reason :)

Comment: Fermi's Golden Rule: the density of final states for emission from the ground state is zero.

Comment: @ JEB My question is nothing to do with Fermi's golden rule.

Comment: @ Wouter I was asking the question in the quantum mechanical framework.