# Kinetic energy (KE) in atomic orbital

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, conventions, quantum-chemistry, orbitals

Within an atomic orbital, electrons must obviously have relative differences between points in space due to potential gradient. But there is kinetic energy as well. If we choose a particular point as zero potential, the electron will have a base level KE here. What determines this KE? In other words, there must be relative differences in KE, but adding a constant everywhere maintains this difference. What determines this constant?

Comment: *"But there is kinetic energy as well."* - [citation needed] The orbital states have a definite energy. Whether that is "kinetic" energy is meaningless, since quantum objects do not move in the classical sense.

Comment: In the Bohr model, electrostatic forces must balance inertial forces. This is why an electron replaced with a heavier particle produces a smaller atomic radius. Within this model, the negative potential energy is equal to 2 times the kinetic energy. I'm sorry to answer your question in a comment, but I've answered this same effective question multiple times on this site already.

Answer (score 4):

Your saying that "*electrons must obviously have relative differences between points in space due to potential gradient*" is not rigorous, because an electron is not a localized object inside an atom, is doesn't occupy a definite point in space. Neither has it a well-defined velocity, nor a well-defined kinetic energy. To put it clearly, the electron is not a Newtonian particle that follows a trajectory and has at every time a position and velocity. There is an uncertainty in its location, and so in its linear momentum.

An interesting discussion on this issue was done by R. Feynman, see the question

[Quantum mechanics,and how the law $ΔxΔp≥ℏ/2$ explains the paradox regarding atoms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156183/quantum-mechanics-and-how-the-law-%ce%94x%ce%94p%e2%89%a5%e2%84%8f-2-explains-the-paradox-regarding-atom#comment327780_156183)

About its kinetic energy, it's the wave-function that can tell you, not the kinetic energy because it doesn't have a precise value, but its **mean value**. If you want to see a calculus, for the electron on the $n$-th level and zero angular momentum ($l = 0$), in the hydrogen atom

$⟨E_K⟩ = \frac {\hbar ^2}{2m_e n^2 a_0^2}$,

(where $a_0$ is the Bohr radius).

Since you speak of choosing a particular point as zero potential, that's quite difficult as in the Coulombian field the potential increases as $1/r$ when approaching the nucleus.

Could it be that you make a confusion? We often refer to $n=1$ level as ground level, and to its **total** energy as ground energy. Thus, for an electron to jump from the ground level to a higher level, the atom needs to absorb the energy difference between the higher level and the ground energy. By the way, total energy is already not an average, but a constant value, typical to each level.