# Is it true that the interior of an atom is mostly vacuum or empty space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, atoms

You often see it written or hear it said that the interior of atoms is mostly empty. 
This is an attempt to convey something about the nature of atoms to a non-expert audience. But is it right? Isn't it rather misleading? Isn't the interior of an atom pretty full up really? (Full up with electrons I mean).

This question is not important to research physics, but it has some
educational significance. It is important to the goal of
conveying correct physical intuition and thus encouraging correct physical insight.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165721/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126512/50583. Technically not a duplicate since that question takes the atom being "empty space" as its premise, but the answers nevertheless discuss the (un)truth of that premise, too.

Comment: I’ve calculated the atom radio [here](https://www.academia.edu/18391675/About_the_distribution_of_electrons_magnetic_dipole_moments_in_atoms_Octahedral_model_) under paragraph 3. The calculation is as simple as effective, the derived electron density matches the covalent radii. A naive work with surprising results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will answer the question by comparing empty space and
vacuum with the properties of the interior of an atom.
I will write at the level of high school physics in order to make my answer accessible.
My conclusion will be that the answer is "no": it is not true that the interior of an atom
is mostly vacuum or empty space, and furthermore
such an idea conveys a thoroughly misleading picture
of the nature of atoms. The main point is that the electrons
are smoothly spread throughout the interior of each atom, and they
carry enough mass and charge to make it misleading to compare
the situation to empty space.

First let's see what we mean by empty space. We mean of course "nothing is there". To flesh this out a little, consider the case of an ordinary
gas at standard temperature and pressure (STP). This is not a vacuum, clearly,
since the pressure is quite high. We might speak of "vacuum" once the
pressure is below a millibar (100 Pa); at STP the pressure is about a bar ($10^5$ Pa). On the other hand it is true to say that such a gas is "mostly empty space" in that the mass is concentrated in the molecules, with almost no mass in between the molecules, and the volume occupied by the molecules is a small fraction (about a thousandth)
of the total. On the other hand, if you place a mass-detector anywhere in the gas, then it will register some mass very quickly, because the
molecules will soon hit it. So to say that a gas is "mostly empty space" is helpful to get the intuition that the molecules can move
freely with a large mean free path, but it can mislead in some respects.

The density of an ordinary gas at STP is about 1 kg/m$^3$.

Now let's think about the interior of an atom. I have in mind some ordinary atom such as carbon, and ordinary locations inside the atom, so not at the nucleus and not far away; one could pick a location about half a Bohr radius from the centre, for example. Let's calculate
some properties.

First, the mass density. This is the mass density owing to the electrons which are present. Their mass is spread throughout the atom
via their extended wavefunctions, and the average mass density can
be estimated by noting that an electron is about 2000 times lighter
than a proton, and a typical atomic nucleus has as many neutrons as protons, so the electrons contribute about one part in 4000 of the total mass. The density of a solid element such as carbon is about 2000 kg/m$^3$
so we can estimate that the density owing to the electrons at a typical place in an atom is about $0.5\, {\rm kg}/{\rm m}^3$. An estimate using the atomic radius of carbon gives the value
8 kg/m$^3$, suggesting that our previous value was an underestimate
because there is some space between the atoms. Anyway the main conclusion
here is that mass density
at a typical spot inside an atom is similar to the average mass density of a gas at STP.

To get the charge density, we multiply the mass density by $q/m_e$,
the charge to mass ratio of an electron,
which gives about $10^{12}$ coulombs per cubic metre.
This is a huge charge density by everyday standards. (For comparison,
a typical
1 microfarad capacitor charged to 1 volt carries a micro-Coulomb in a volume of order $10^{-7}$ m$^3$, giving a charge density $10$ C/m$^3$.)

Next let's consider the flux of matter---the rate at which mass
will approach and hit a detector if we were able to place a mass-detector
inside our atom. The electrons have speeds of order a few times
$\alpha c$ where $\alpha \simeq 1/137$ is the fine structure constant
and $c$ is the speed of light. The flux (mass crossing unit area per
unit time) is therefore around $8 \times 3\times 10^8 / 137 \simeq
10^7$ kg per second per square metre. Needless to say, this is a huge
value in everyday terms.

Next let's enquire into whether or not there is "empty space" in the sense that there is room to put stuff inside an atom. The original statement perhaps comes from a desire to compare an atom to a gas,
using some notion that electrons are point-like in some sense, with
room in between them.

To address this question we need some more advanced physical ideas, to
do with the Pauli exclusion principle. This is an important result in quantum physics, which says that particles such as electrons cannot overlap one another completely. To be precise, in any given spatial situation there can be at most two electrons having that particular combination of position and momentum.

What this means in practice is that there is no more room for low-energy
electrons in any atom. If the atom is a hotel, then all the rooms on the
lower floors are occupied---completely full up. Thus the
space inside an atom is completely unavailable to further electrons
unless they move quickly. This is about as far from "empty space" as you can get. It is "complete and utterly full-up space", as far
as low-energy electrons are concerned. But this does not exclude electrons altogether, as I already said. If they are moving quickly
then there is room for further electrons to get into an atom. They
won't stay there---they would have to form a beam passing through;
they are visitors to the guests staying in the hotel. For an extra electron
bound to an atom (making a negatively charged ion), the wavefunction of
the extra electron does get inside the atom a bit (it penetrates the
core, as we say), and this can be compared with a visitor rapidly
visiting again and again.

What about other types of particle---say, neutrons? They can more
easily enter an atom. But is the experience of a neutron sitting inside
an atom anything like the experience of a neutron sitting in empty
space? Hardly. They would be continually bombarded by that high flux
of electrons we calculated just now, and they would notice because
although they carry no electric charge, neutrons carry a substantial
magnetism, and this leads to an electromagnetic interaction between the
neutron and all the nearby electrons.

Now let's summarize.

Electrons in atoms behave in ways that classical physics cannot
account for; we require quantum physics. As a result, when we talk about
atoms in everyday language, we are trying to convey in everyday terms what quantum physics says is going on. Among the things that quantum physics tells us about the interior of an atom is that the electrons are
smoothly spread out, such that the probability of an electron being present at any given moment is non-zero throughout the interior of
an atom. We can flesh this out a little by calculating properties such
as mass density and charge density and flux. The mass density of
the electron cloud of a typical atom is similar to the average
mass density of an ordinary gas at standard temperature and pressure.
The flux is huge and the charge density is enormous. Also, it is strictly impossible to introduce further slow-moving electrons into the inside
of an atom, but it is possible for fast-moving electrons to pass through. Neutrons can also enter atoms, and when inside they interact
with the electrons which are there.

In view of the above, it seems to me that it is misleading to say that
the interior of atoms is anything like either vacuum or empty space.
It really isn't. But it seems that this idea has become lodged into popular
presentations of science. It will take some effort to dislodge it.

I now wonder where this idea came from in the first place.
I think possibly it might have originated in the early attempts to
model atoms via classical point-like particles, or perhaps it is
descended from the "fly in a cathedral" image, which is a correct
statement about the relative sizes of the atomic nucleus and the
whole atom. The "fly in a cathedral" seems to imply that the rest
of the "cathedral" is empty, but it is not. It is full of electrons.

Comment: Most of this answer is accessible to an A-level student. It could also be presented in part as guided exercises with a clear and worthwhile purpose.

Comment: Nice. As far from where or how the idea was developed I think is shifting from Thomson to Rutherford model. In the latter nothing was well defined about electrons in terms of their motion, but it opened the room for an empty space inside the atom. Nice Q and A.

Comment: What about the viewpoint that electrons inhabit specific shells, spreading out on each shell, but with empty space between the shells?

Comment: @Halsey In fact the wavefunction associated with each shell overlaps quite a lot with the others; there are no gaps. But thanks for this and I might add a sentence on it to my answer.

Comment: There is no need to justify a self-answer: the process is not only sanctioned, but explicitly supported by the UI.

Comment: @D.Halsey The "shells" are spacing filling probability distributions (well, there are a few nodes, but....) rather than discrete radial regions.

Comment: @ dmckee  But does that imply that there is no empty space in the atom?

Answer (score 6):

I would take your sentence

> It is important to the goal of conveying correct physical intuition
> and thus encouraging correct physical insight.

as a central guideline in my answer, as you'll see,  my conclusions are quite different.

The origin of the statement about the almost empty interior of an atom comes from the thorough Rutherford's analysis (1911) [1] of the Geiger and Marsden experiment of alpha particles scattering by thin gold foils. Rutherford did not write explicitly such expression, but the key point of his analysis was to show that a model of the atom made by a *spatially concentrated* heavy particle whose charge should be proportional to the atomic weight was able to account for the experimental data much better than a diffuse density of the scattering component. Therefore, the main emphasis in Rutherford's paper was more on the "concentrated" character of the scattering component than on the presence of an "empty space."

However, such last inference was quite natural once one considers the positive nuclei as the main source of scattering if the second atomic component, the electrons, are considered point-like particles. An unavoidable step more than 10 years before the birth of wave mechanics.

So, from a historical perspective, the sentence corresponds to a well definite and historically justifiable point of view.

Now, let's examine the situation with today's eyes.
What could be a correct statement? The interior of the atom is empty? Is it full of something? Electrons? Fields?

Here, I'm afraid I have to disagree with your idea that

> The main point is that the electrons are smoothly spread throughout
> the interior of each atom, and they carry enough mass and charge to
> make it misleading to compare the situation to empty space.

I am afraid that such a statement would enforce a common misconception which tries to maintain the original idea of the "waves of matter" proposed by de Broglie and eliminated from the possible interpretations of QM since the analysis of scattering processes made by Born and resulting in the present-day probabilistic interpretation of QM.

From a pedagogical point of view, the key point is to insist that all the existing experiments agree on a point-like structure of the electron. Measuring charge or mass density would be misleading, since it would convey the idea that it is possible to detect part of an electron.

In summary, I would not insist too much on the sentence about "empty space" in the atom if not connected with Rutherford's analysis. But certainly, I would not substitute it with potentially wrong ideas about an extended electron.

---

[1] Professor E. Rutherford F.R.S. (1911) LXXIX. The scattering of α and β particles by matter and the structure of the atom, The London, Edinburgh, and Dublin Philosophical Magazine and Journal of Science, 21:125, 669-688, DOI: 10.1080/14786440508637080

Comment: Thanks for this. I agree one should be cautious about implying the electron is extended, and there was a (quiet) hint of such caution in my answer, but this does not change the main point that atomic interiors really are very unlike empty space. The plane wave modes employed in quantum field theory are de Broglie waves; they have not been abandoned so much as learned about more. The probability of detecting an electron at any given place inside an atom is non-zero at all times and places; the charge density is used in atomic structure calculations.

Comment: @AndrewSteane I know very well that charge density is used in electronic structure calculations, and "observed" in STM experiments. However, I keep thinking that it may be misleading to insist on something that could easily be confused with a continuum description. Plane  waves modes used in QFT are quite more sophisticated than de Broglie waves, IMO. But, a part these divergencies of opinion, I would put the emphasize on the difference that the concept of "empty' or "crowded" may have in the present context. At the end of the day in the hydrogen atom there is just one electron and one proton.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to look at the "interior of an atom is mostly vacuum" sentence is to think about mass distribution. In some sense the sentence is true: most of the mass is concentrated in a very small volume (the nucleus). Compared to the nucleus, the rest of the space is occupied by electron orbitals, which matter density (or better, the energy density) is many orders of magnitude lower (so almost "vacuum" from this point of view).

It is just a non-technical way of conveying the idea that the atom structure is "similar" to a "dense" planet that is extremely small but is surrounded by a rarefied atmosphere that contributes almost nothing to the total mass. Maybe a ineffective analogy for someone, but useful to give to the general public the idea that you do not need to be massive to occupy space.

Comment: Thanks for this answer focusing on mass, which is of course an important aspect here. The motivation for the question came partly from a wish to consider why atoms don't interpenetrate each other very much (in ordinary circumstances). It is largely because they are already "full" (owing to the physics which leads to the  Pauli exclusion principle). But we should not overlook the interesting fact about where the mass is concentrated, as you say.

Comment: Quilio is correct in the sense that almost all of the matter of an atom is concentrated at its center in a relative very small volume compared to the total volume of the atom including its electrons's atmosphere. I agree however also that the term "mostly occupied by empty void space" is misleading. The electron atmosphere of condensed stable matter atoms is a very active region in space with high kinetic energy (i.e. charge) and magnetic flux that although the mass density is relative very small comparable to an imperfect vacuum any foreign sub-particle will have a hard time to stay.

Comment: @Andrew Steane You're right. Popular science cliché like this should be used with caution from educators and not without further justification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people write such excessive comments on this one...
The atom is surrounded by an electron cloud. But the electron cloud's mass density is comparatively small to that of the core. Most of the mass you interact with, is located at the core. In this picture, the electron cloud is simply considered "vacuum".
But the electron cloud communicates the forces you need to interact with other objects.

Comment: Just to make the point why mass is not the only consideration that matters, suppose that $10^{23}$ electrons impacted on your body in some way, all at once (at some modest speed). In this scenario the mass involved is $\sim 10^{-6}$ kg which you would not notice, but the charge is about $10^5$ coulombs which you certainly would notice. The associated fields would rip your body apart. So such an object would not be considered 'vacuum' in comparison to even a 1 kg ordinary object. Similarly, I think, we should not suggest that the interior of an atom is anything like vacuum or empty space.