# motion of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

Do electrons move randomly, with no preference of directions?
And why electrons don't fall into the nucleus? About this question, I read the article on Chemistry wiki, which says that when electron falls towards nucleus, its kinetic energy becomes extremely large so there is a battle between electrons and nucleus, and no one is gonna win the battle, there is a compromise state instead. My question is why can't we say that electrons with great kinetic energy are moving towards the nucleus? Why should it escape？

Comment: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Physical_Chemistry/Quantum_Mechanics/Atomic_Theory/Why_atoms_do_not_Collapse

Comment: this is the website

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30939/

Comment: This  might help http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20003/