# Basic concepts on Electricity

Tags: electricity, electrons, atomic-physics, conductors

1. How do electrons move?
2. I mean really do they move?
3. I read that they move in circular shells AROUND THE NUCLEUS. How can they move in the conductor?
4. I have read that there are valent electrons that jump! How can they jump?
5. Why do we use "current means motion of POSITIVE IONS"?
6. Ions are full atoms?
7. Then what does actually move?
8. And how?

I have tried to read many thing on google but they confuse me more.

Comment: I won't really advice you to dig in this topic for now. You CBSE board will make you even confused. Study the electricity chapter, get some foreign book like Halliday Resnick and read it's chapter. It's a vast topic. You will get even more confused here. Though you are welcome to try. I see many newbies in problem due to this. I don't face this problem, but if you do I would advice you to follow my steps.

Comment: Related: [How do electrons jump orbitals?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46801/how-do-electrons-jump-orbitals/47137#47137)

Comment: All of that needs quantum mechanics to answer correctly, which is why you are so confused. You are in good company, just 100 years ago the best physicists in the world were just as confused as you are!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is the model of the atom that I think you will best understand. It is called the Bohr model of the atom. As you cans see, the valence electrons are at the very edge.

[image]

Metals conduct electricity so easily because their valence electrons are not tightly bound. To put it more simply, the outer electrons can move around freely, without being held back.

Comment: Yep. That's all you need to learn now to prevent being confused. - To the asker of question.