# Can a particle move from one place to another without traversing the space in between?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, kinematics, wavefunction, orbitals

Say I measure a quantum particle at some place, and then I find it at another place.
According to my understanding of wavefunctions  the particle can get from one place to another without traversing the space in between
Is this phenomena a consequence of Quantum Mechanics or have i got it wrong?

Comment: The duplicate question isn't *exactly* the same '(you're not asking about orbitals), but that doesn't change anything fundamental and e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/47137/50583) discusses exactly what you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you but direct answers to this question would have been more informative.

Comment: If you have something that's not answered by the linked duplicate, please edit your question to point out what specifically you want to know that's not covered there.

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/488540/123208