# What causes electron to orbit the nucleus in an atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

What causes the electron to orbit the nucleus? Which is the force that causes it to do so?  Is it related to the Electro         -        Magnetic force? .

Comment: Hi Aparajita, please specify your doubt? What do you believe? Electrodynamics is a field, do you mean electrostatics coulomb force? If yes, then you are right, it is electrostatics coulomb force that provides necessary centripetal force to electron for circling around the nucleus.

Comment: I meant electrostatic force, I actually wanted to ask why do electrons move at all? What makes them move?

Comment: Consider this, an electron that is away from the positive nucleus (i.e. which is not part of the atom) gets attracted toward it due to electrostatics force.

Comment: Than you Orion, but what gives them the speed? Is it electrostatic force again?

Comment: Quantum physical rules does not allow it to fall inside nucleus and hence it starts orbiting around it. When it started orbiting in the nth orbit, it had the angular momentum $n\hbar$. It keeps on orbiting due to conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9415/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This was not the question asked by me, it has been edited

Answer (score 5):

It *doesn't* actually orbit the nucleus in the modern quantum mechanical understanding of the atom, although in a classical approximation, some properties relating to electron energy levels, etc. can be reproduced in terms of the picture of an "orbiting electron"*.

The reason you have an orbiting electron in the classical model is also related to this, as the only way the classical model can (try to) explain a stationary point-electron that isn't collapsing into the nucleus is to say the electron is spinning really fast. Note that "classical" in this sense also includes the Bohr model, which is entirely classical except it follows the old quantum rule $\int p\,dq=n\hbar$.

*as an example -- the energy levels in a quantum atom are given as $\sqrt{1-\alpha^2Z^2}$ where the fine structure constant $\alpha\approx1/137$, which is why you don't have atoms with more than 137 electrons. But in the classical picture, this gets re-interpreted as saying "the outer electron will have to move faster than light if you get more than 137 electrons", which has the same impact on the real-ness of the energy level.

Comment: I mean what makes them move at all

Comment: Why did you edit my question? My question is simple , why do the electrons move at all?

Comment: @APARAJITA: Because it was not clear that way, so I clarified it. I did answer the "what makes them move at all", in the secondf part.